# How to video write with yolo async function

Tags: python, opencv, asynchronous

I'm developing automatic recording system with YOLO and ZED stereo camera(60fps).

I run YOLO every second, and when person detected, keep recording video.
And if False result comes out 5 times, stop recording.

However, while YOLO is running frames are dropped and not recorded on video.
So I want to apply async function in my code, but it didn't work.

This is my test pseudo code.
Video is record perfectly and no frame drop but yolo is not run.

```
import time
from utils.detect import YoloONNX
from common.config import VIDEO_CODEC
from utils.util import *
import cv2
import imutils
import os
import numpy as np
import pyzed.sl as sl
import asyncio

model = YoloONNX("./models/yolov7.onnx")

async def prepare_detect_person(frame):
    try:
        print('prepare_detect_person')
        frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=600)
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        await loop.run_in_executor(None, detect_person, frame)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error occurred: {str(e)}")
def detect_person(frame):
    res = model.onnx_inference(frame)

async def main():
    zed = sl.Camera()

    init_params = sl.InitParameters()
    init_params.camera_resolution = sl.RESOLUTION.HD720
    init_params.camera_fps = 60

    err = zed.open(init_params)
    if err != sl.ERROR_CODE.SUCCESS:
        print("Camera Open : "+repr(err)+". Exit program.")
        exit()

    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*VIDEO_CODEC)
    video_writer = cv2.VideoWriter('./async_test.mp4', fourcc, 60,(1280, 720))
    i = 0
    max_frame = 10000
    image = sl.Mat()
    runtime_parameters = sl.RuntimeParameters()
    while i < max_frame:
        if zed.grab(runtime_parameters) == sl.ERROR_CODE.SUCCESS:
            zed.retrieve_image(image, sl.VIEW.LEFT)
            frame = image.get_data()
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2RGB)
            if i % 30 == 0:
                print(f'start detect person')
                # await prepare_detect_person(frame)
                asyncio.create_task(prepare_detect_person(frame))
            i += 1
            video_writer.write(frame)

    video_writer.release()
    zed.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
    loop.close()
```

Can I video write without frame drop while running YOLO model?

Answer (score 0):

correct it with this code

```
import cv2
import imutils
import asyncio
import numpy as np
import pyzed.sl as sl
from utils.detect import YoloONNX
from common.config import VIDEO_CODEC

model = YoloONNX("./models/yolov7.onnx")

async def detect_person(frame):
    try:
        print('Detecting person...')
        res = model.onnx_inference(frame)
        return res  # Assuming the model.onnx_inference returns something indicating detection success
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error occurred: {str(e)}")
        return False

async def main():
    zed = sl.Camera()

    init_params = sl.InitParameters()
    init_params.camera_resolution = sl.RESOLUTION.HD720
    init_params.camera_fps = 60

    err = zed.open(init_params)
    if err != sl.ERROR_CODE.SUCCESS:
        print("Camera Open : "+repr(err)+". Exit program.")
        exit()

    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*VIDEO_CODEC)
    video_writer = cv2.VideoWriter('./async_test.mp4', fourcc, 60,(1280, 720))
    i = 0
    max_frame = 10000
    image = sl.Mat()
    runtime_parameters = sl.RuntimeParameters()
    false_results_count = 0

    while i < max_frame:
        if zed.grab(runtime_parameters) == sl.ERROR_CODE.SUCCESS:
            zed.retrieve_image(image, sl.VIEW.LEFT)
            frame = image.get_data()
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2RGB)

            if i % 30 == 0:
                detection_result = await detect_person(frame)
                if detection_result:
                    false_results_count = 0
                else:
                    false_results_count += 1

                if false_results_count >= 5:
                    print("Stopping recording...")
                    break

            i += 1
            video_writer.write(frame)

    video_writer.release()
    zed.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: What I want is a video recording code that doesn't drop the frame. This still drops frame when the YOLO model runs. I want to record the video at the same time as the YOLO model runs.